# What is the differential form of a composition

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

I would like to be able to calculate $\alpha(X_0\circ X_1)$ for $\alpha\in\Omega^1$ the set of 1-forms.

Is it $X_0(\alpha(X_1))$?

At least that is what I would like it to be but how can I get there?

Comment: Are $X_0$ and $X_1$ vector fields? If so, what does $X_0\circ X_1$ mean?

Comment: ^ +1. If you mean the composition of vector fields as differential operators, then the result is not a vector field; so $\alpha(X_0 \circ X_1)$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: My reasoning was: They are vector fields and so can be seen as derivations of $C^\infty(M)$. Therefore composition makes sense. When you compose both, you get a derivation which again can be interpreted as a vector field.

Comment: However actually a composition of derivations is not a derivation as I have just noticed by developing. I was interested in finding $\alpha(X_0\circ X_1)$ to try and calculate $\alpha[X_0,X_1] = \alpha(X_0\circ X_1 - X_1\circ X_0)$ since $[X_0,X_1](f) = X_0(X_1(f)) - X_1(X_0(F))$